# Angular, parsing array out of JSON object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm wanting to iterate through multiple JSON objects i've pulled from my database to display the containing data. I'm having trouble getting comments, comments contains an array of strings, however, when i'm passing the objects out they're reamining objects.

Here are my JSON objects:

```
{
  eventShow :
  [
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5898dabd721461267c6b0ca6"),
            "username" : "larry",
            "type" : "Crosscountry",
            "name" : "Muddy run",
            "rating" : 8,
            "description" : "Had a brilliant time, got a bit dirty but would definitely recommend!",
            "distance" : "6",
            "comments" : [
                    "Looks like you had fun, would love to join you next time!",
                    "This definitley isn't my kind of thing..."
            ],
            "__v" : 0
    },
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5898e575721461267c6b0ca7"),
            "username" : "larry",
            "type" : "Short distance bike ride",
            "name" : "Bike sprint!",
            "rating" : 10,
            "description" : "Gotta go fast!",
            "distance" : "1",
            "comments" : [ ],
            "__v" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

My HTML:

```
<ul ng-show="hasEvent" ng-repeat="x in eventShow">
  <li>
    {{'Event Name: ' + x.name}}
  </li>
  <li>
     {{'Type: ' + x.type}}
   </li>
   <li>
     {{'Distance: ' + x.distance + ' miles'}}
   </li>
   <li>
     {{'Rating: ' + x.rating}}
   </li>
   <li>
     {{'Description: ' + x.description}}
   </li>
</ul>
   <hr>
<div class="actionBox">
    <ul class="commentList" ng-repeat="y in x.comments">
        <li>
            <div class="commentText">
                <p class="">{{y}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How would I go about displaying all comments in a readable fashion, would JSON.stringify() be the right way to go?

A $http.get() which retrieves the JSON object from my mongoDB database is being called from my backend and passing a JSON object back to my services, which is being called from my controller, then... A JSON object is being passed into $scope.eventShow.

I've managed to display all comments with a nested ng-repeat however still need to get them as strings. [As shown here](https://puu.sh/tRp4g/37f820077f.png)

Comment: Post your controller code, please, so we can see how you're currently attempting to get and use the data.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (based on your json single object):

```
<ul ng-show="hasEvent">
  <li>{{'Event Name: ' + eventShow.name}}</li>
  <li>{{'Type: ' + eventShow.type}}</li>
  <li>{{'Distance: ' + eventShow.distance + ' miles'}}</li>
  <li>{{'Rating: ' + eventShow.rating}}</li>
  <li>{{'Description: ' + eventShow.description}}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div class="actionBox">
  <ul class="commentList" ng-repeat="x in eventShow.comments">
    <li>
      <div class="commentText">
        <p>{{x}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you *want* to have nested loop and json object in your example is one object in some array (eventShow), then you will need second level ng-repeat for "x.comments"

**UPDATE**
For nesting outside of dom children, you need to use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<ul ng-show="hasEvent" ng-repeat-start="x in eventShow">
  <li>{{'Event Name: ' + x.name}}</li>
  <li>{{'Type: ' + x.type}}</li>
  <li>{{'Distance: ' + x.distance + ' miles'}}</li>
  <li>{{'Rating: ' + x.rating}}</li>
  <li>{{'Description: ' + x.description}}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div class="actionBox" ng-repeat-end>
  <ul class="commentList" ng-repeat="y in x.comments">
    <li>
      <div class="commentText">
        <p>{{y}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, should've made it clearer, thought it may have been implicit from my html, I've actually got multiple JSON objects, i'm having trouble with the nested ng-repeat, I still can't get t he comments displaying as strings.

Comment: I've managed to display all the comments using a nested ng-repeat. [As shown here](https://puu.sh/tRoNb/460bd6a693.png)

Comment: Unfortunately still not what i'm looking for; producing the same result. @laser

Comment: @Roadhouse are you sure that your JSON is what you describe it is. Something different in "comments" field (is it really array, not object)? If you move nested loop inside of </ul> of outer loop in your sample it SHOULD provide correct result (you can check it), if result as you describe, then study the json object for validity

Comment: @Roadhouse for object you need to iterate over (key, value), example: ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"

Comment: {"0":"L","1":"o","2":"o","3":"k"}, it seems to be going into eventShow as an object. Iterating through the key and displaying the value should work in this instance, thanks. @laser

Comment: using (key, value) pair on y in x.comments would produce something like:

 
0{"0":"L","1":"o","2":"o","3":"k"}

1{"0":"T","1":"h","2":"i","3":"s") @laser

Comment: @do you have plunker example? I cannot help without extra knowledge.

Comment: never used plunker before, i'll try get one set up tomorrow if i haven't figured it out. Need to take a break; i've been coding for ~12 hours today. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You put `x.comments` outside the `ng-repeat`.  Also, you're missing a comma between the objects in the outer array.

Answer (score 0):

To access an array from inside ng-repeat, if you need auto increment variable you can use $index+1 for an array.(in your code y[$index+1]). You can try code below as well.

```
<ul ng-show="hasEvent" ng-repeat="x in eventShow">
   <li>
       {{'Event Name: ' + x.name}}
   </li>
   <li>
       {{'Type: ' + x.type}}
   </li>
   <li>
       {{'Distance: ' + x.distance + ' miles'}}
  </li>
  <li>
      {{'Rating: ' + x.rating}}
  </li>
  <li>
      {{'Description: ' + x.description}}
  </li>
</ul>

 <hr>

 <div class="actionBox">
  <ul class="commentList" ng-repeat="y in x.comments track by $index">
      <li>
          <div class="commentText">
              <p class="">{{y}} </p>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tried this solution and I'm producing the same output.

Comment: Looks like this is on the right tracks, i need to pull every other index of the array. {"0":"L","1":"o","2":"o","3":"k"}, index 1, 3, 5 and 7. "Look". @chetasmehta

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: My logic was correct and everything is now working. The problem was how I was setting up my database Schema.